# Cannot install npm package in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, npm-install

I clone my project from GitLab and I need to install the NPM packages in my project.

When I run `npm install` it shows me this error:

[image: Error]

and I go to the log file and see:

```
30601 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...19"},"dist":{"integri'
30601 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
30601 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
30601 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50
30601 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
30602 verbose cwd /home/mrcoder/Projects/Angular/Ava/PFA/pfa-front-cpl
30603 verbose Linux 5.4.0-33-generic
30604 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
30605 verbose node v12.17.0
30606 verbose npm  v6.14.4
30607 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...19"},"dist":{"integri'
30608 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "vex",
  "version": "9.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/material": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.7",
    "@iconify/icons-emojione": "~1.0.5",
    "@iconify/icons-fa-brands": "~1.0.10",
    "@iconify/icons-fa-solid": "~1.0.8",
    "@iconify/icons-ic": "~1.0.9",
    "@iconify/icons-logos": "~1.0.9",
    "@ngrx/store": "^9.1.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "~5.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "~5.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@visurel/iconify-angular": "^0.0.7",
    "angular-calendar": "~0.28.5",
    "angular2-promise-buttons": "^4.0.6",
    "apexcharts": "~3.17.0",
    "color": "~3.1.2",
    "date-fns": "~2.11.0",
    "highlight.js": "~9.18.1",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.3",
    "luxon": "~1.22.0",
    "ng2-jalali-date-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-quill": "~8.1.0",
    "ngx-showdown": "~5.1.0",
    "ngx-take-until-destroy": "~5.4.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "quill": "~1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "showdown": "^1.9.1",
    "simplebar": "~4.2.3",
    "tailwindcss": "~1.2.0",
    "tslib": "~1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.7",
    "@fullhuman/purgecss-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/color": "~3.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/luxon": "~1.22.0",
    "@types/node": "~13.9.3",
    "@types/showdown": "~1.9.3",
    "@types/simplebar": "~5.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "postcss-loader": "~3.0.0",
    "postcss-scss": "~2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "tailwindcss-dir": "~4.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.8.1",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

What's the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: You need to show us your `package,json` instead of `angular.json` when you're `npm install`ing

Comment: `19"},"dist":{"integri` doesn't appear in the `angular.json`, so it's unclear why you're showing it. Check the other JSON files you have; `package{,-lock}.json`, for example.

Comment: `19"},"dist":{"integri` isn't in `package.json` either. Look for the file that **contains that text**, that's what's failing to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are having some issue in your package-lock.json. Because package-lock.json inserts a integrity key with each dependency in that json. Sometimes that json gets disformed/corrupted so when npm goes to read it next time to figure out what version of dependency to install. It gives this kind of error. The steps given below can resolve this issue.

1. Delete package-lock.json.
2. Delete node_modules
3. Run npm cache clean --force
4. Run npm install.

Answer (score -1):

Try `npm cache clean --force` and then reinstall using `npm install`.

Hope it works! :)

Comment: If it doesn't work, please attach your package.json file